# I'm having issue with counting with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, statistics, mathematica, analysis, accounting

Excel work screenshot:
[image: Excel spreadsheet]

I need to count the amount of blank cells in "days utilized" judging by the year "2009" in "year started" row. The answer is 1, but I didn't get it with the right formula calculation that would work in every case/instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
=COUNTIFS(B5:B17, 2009, D5:D17, "=")
```

You need to use [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) to use multiple criteria - in this case, you want both the year to be 2009 *and* the cell to be blank at the same time.

Related: [How do I get countifs to select all non-blank cells in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772225/how-do-i-get-countifs-to-select-all-non-blank-cells-in-excel)

Comment: Thank you very much @andrewmorton you did a very good job!! This worked in the blink of an eye!!!...

Comment: So, in this case, what does "=" serves as? I've tried using it as; " " / "*" due to some things that I found on the net, but it was giving me the result as "0"

Comment: @Peacefulpeace It's how you check for the contents of the cell being equal to an empty string in COUNTIFS. It isn't exactly intuitive...

Comment: Oh!! I tried doing that even without reading such, but I was actually trying to upvote. It kept on saying I don't have enough reputation, and I needed at least 15 to cast a vote. So, I had to abadon it. Thanks for the tip BTW.

Comment: If I may ask, one of the question in this assignment says to "Make a line graph of "Year Started" against "Amount of Books" is the diagram above correct as per the word 'against' ??

Comment: @Peacefulpeace That's answered in [Is x plotted against y or is y plotted against x?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/107800/231007)